# Unable to build Docker image for Arm32v7 with external assembly

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, .net-6.0

I have an aspnet application which is using an external Assembly (from another project of mine).

I have added this as a project reference, and I can build and run my application locally fine, with no errors or problems.
But when trying to build this for Docker with Arm32v7 (Raspberry Pi) I get the error:

> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
> the assembly "SAM Shared". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
> disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
> compilation errors.

My docker file

```
#Below is changed to use the appropiate image for Rpi, arm32v7
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.1-bullseye-slim-arm32v7 AS base 
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["HomeMonitor/HomeMonitor.csproj", "HomeMonitor/"]
COPY ["HomeMonitor.Shared/HomeMonitor.Shared.csproj", "HomeMonitor.Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "HomeMonitor/HomeMonitor.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/HomeMonitor"
RUN dotnet build "HomeMonitor.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HomeMonitor.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HomeMonitor.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This drove my crazy for ages, and stopped me progressing with my project.

I didn't really find a solution, but more of a workaround, or actually 2!

**First workaround**

Initially as my external Assembly was relatively small and stable, then I simply created a copy and added it as a new project in this solution.  I could then add it as a reference

This worked, and I could compile and run my image on docker.  But was not really a solution.

**Second workaround**

This is probably closer to a full solution, but doesn't really fix the original problem so much as avoid it so hence I still consider it a bit of a workaround and it might not suit everybody.

I went back to my external assembly and I packaged it as a nuget package.  I then uploaded it to a private package on Github.  This was actually much easier than I realised (never done it before) and I found this good video to guide me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiPkYrqJsps

Then I could add it as a nuget package in my project.  And this then worked perfectly, and I had no more issues.